# How to understand this excerpt from the book, "Think Java"?

Tags: java, object

The problem arises in the line

```
String pls = printABCS("A", "B", "c", "D", "E", "F,", "G");"
```

and I have no idea why, I've tried for the past hour and nothing seems to be working. Is there any fix to why when I run the code, the result is

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method printABCS(Time3) in the type Time3 is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String, String, String, String)

at chapter11.Time3.main(Time3.java:16)"
```

Thanks for taking your time to help.

```
public class Time3 {
    String a, b, c, d, e, f, g;

    public Time3(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e, String f, String g) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.e = e;
    this.f = f;
    this.g = g;

  }
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String pls = printABCS("A", "B", "c", "D", "E", "F,", "G");

  }
  public static String printABCS(Time3 p) {
    return (p.a + p.b + p.c + p.d + p.e + p.f + p.g);
  }

}
```

Comment: The method expects a Time3. You're passing a bunch of Strings. Hence the error "not applicable for the arguments (String,...)."

Comment: As @AndyThomas said, you are trying to pass the wrong *Object(s)* to a method. The `printABCS` method is declared to take as input an object called `Time3`. You're passing 7 Strings. It doesn't know what to do with that, hence the compilation issue. Consider constructing a `Time3` object if you can, otherwise change the method signature to take Strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoke the method `printABCS` and pass a set of strings to it. But the signature of the method only accepts a `Time3` object, thus the compilation error.

But: the Time3 class has a constructor accepting strings. Create a new `Time3` instance and pass the arguments to it

```
String pls = printABCS(new Time3("A", "B", "c", "D", "E", "F,", "G"));
```

If its a good book you're reading, it should contain the concepts "Constructors" and "Signature (of methods)", look them up.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
    public class Time3 {
    String a, b, c, d, e, f, g;

    public Time3(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e, String f, String g) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.e = e;
    this.f = f;
    this.g = g;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Time3 t = new Time3("A", "B", "c", "D", "E", "F,", "G");
     String pls = printABCS(t);
     System.out.println(pls);
     }
     public static String printABCS(Time3 p) {
         return (p.a + p.b + p.c + p.d + p.e + p.f + p.g);
     }

  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I understand a lot better now! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on track, you just missed little thing in there. You need to create an instance of the class Time3 and put in that instance in your printABC() method because it accept only an instance. loook

```
public class Time3 {
    private String a, b, c, d, e, f, g;

    public Time3(String a,String b, String c, String d, String e, String f, String g){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
        this.e = e;
        this.f = f;
        this.g = g;
    }

    public static String printABC(Time3 p){
        return p.a + p.b + p.c + p.d + p.e + p.f + p.g;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Time3 time1 = new Time3("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G");
        String pls = printABC(time1);
        System.out.println(pls);
    }
}
```